# Cannot use HardwareSerial pointers or references in my Lib for Arduino AVR?

Tags: arduino, library, c++

I wrote a wrapper class for a serial lcd screen for 4dulcd - and i want to be able to pass which serial i am using to communicate with it

I have these in my code
myClass.h

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

public:
uint8_t Init(long BaudRate, HardwareSerial *serial);

private:
HardwareSerial *_HardSerial;
```

in myClass.cpp

```
uint8_t myClass::Init(long BaudRate, HardwareSerial *serial){
_HardSerial(serial);
...
}
```

In my sketch

```
#include <myClass.h>  
myClass lcd;  


void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);  // <- Error here?!
  //lcd.Init(115000,&Serial1);
...
```

So the error is

> sketch_sep17a.cpp: In function 'void setup()': sketch_sep17a:16:
>   error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

If i remove the myClass.h header than the Serial1 works... i Include it and it throws this error that makes no sense to-

I tried to include the hardwareserial in my sketch and make an instance of it but it requires all sorts of construction properties that i have no idea what they mean. And i would not even want to release my lib to do this as it is inconvenient for the normal end user.

I tried both references and pointers- same error.

Can any body help?

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but where is Serial1 instantiated?

If there is no Serial1 object created then unless the begin function is static it won't work.

Comment: Serial1 is auto instantiated in the Harwarewareserial.cpp ... which by default is loaded in the Arduino IDE. somehow by including the hwserial.h header in my Lib-- it no longer knows what Serial1 is anymore..?but it should..